# Lag when loading downloaded AssetBundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've updated to Unity 2017.1. When I instantiate an object on scene from bundle the app freezes for 1-3 seconds. I didn't notice this problem on previous Unity version, but I don't want to downgrade to 5.6.

```
IEnumerator LoadAssetBundle(WWW www)
{
    EventLisaner.Instance.SetAudioStation(false);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        int current = (int)(www.progress * 100);
        progressText.text = string.Format("Загрузка модели {0}%", current.ToString());
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            Destroy(destroyBundle);
            bundle.Unload(true);

        }
        bundle = www.assetBundle;
        StartCoroutine(InstantiationBundle());
    }
    else
    {
        loaderUI.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private IEnumerator InstantiationBundle()
{
    GameObject inst = bundle.LoadAsset("prefab") as GameObject;
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(inst);

    obj.transform.SetParent(RayCam.selectObj.transform.parent, false);
    obj.AddComponent<VuforiaMove>();
    loaderUI.SetActive(false);
    destroyBundle = obj;
    EventLisaner.Instance.enabledLoadBundle = true;
    EventLisaner.Instance.enbledNextTrekingDonload = true;
    yield return null;
}
```

UPD: I've determined that bug appears on this line: `bundle = www.assetBundle;`. I've tried to do `yield return bundle = www.assetBundle;` but it didn't seem to help. Still having that freeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only line of code that can cause this freeze is `bundle.LoadAsset`.This is loading and de-serializing the AssetBundle in the main thread. You have to use the async version of this function which is `LoadAssetAsync` then yield it to finish loading. It will do the loading in another thread. The coroutine is simply used to wait for that operation being performed in another thread to finish.

Replace

```
GameObject inst = bundle.LoadAsset("prefab") as GameObject;
```

with

```
AssetBundleRequest request = bundle.LoadAssetAsync("prefab");
//Wait for load
yield return request;
GameObject inst = request.asset as GameObject;
```

The rest of the code should be the-same.

**EDIT**:

If `www.assetBundle` is causing the issue, remove that line of code and use `AssetBundle.LoadFromMemoryAsync(www.bytes)` to load the Assetbundle. you will have to pass `WWW` to the `InstantiationBundle` function.

```
private IEnumerator InstantiationBundle(WWW www)
{
    AssetBundleCreateRequest createRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromMemoryAsync(www.bytes);
    yield return createRequest;

    AssetBundle bundle = createRequest.assetBundle;

    AssetBundleRequest request = bundle.LoadAssetAsync("prefab");
    //Wait for load
    yield return request;
    GameObject inst = request.asset as GameObject;

    ....
    .....
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: You should also rebuild your AssetBundles since you updated Unity.

Comment: Thanks for reply, sir, but it didn't help :(

Comment: I found, that bug appears on line `bundle = www.assetBundle`. Maybe this will help to solve the problem

Comment: Yes. After I commented the line `StartCoroutine(InstantiationBundle());` freeze remained, so the problem is not in it. But after I commented `bundle = www.assetBundle;` freeze disappeared.

Comment: Check the edit. That might fix your issue. Although I am araid that `createRequest.assetBundle` may cause that same issue too but try my EDIT.

Comment: You are welcome. Changed the title to reflect the problem.